# I have some trouble with multi threading

Tags: multithreading

I am struggling with this code. It's about counting some patterns from a text file. I tried to use thread(divide and conquer) processing, but it return a wrong value. I used mutex value to synchronize critical section.. The code is below. First main argument is number of threads,  second is the name of a text file I want counting patterns from, and following patterns I want to look up on the text.
please save me..

Code is below

---

```
char *buffer;
int fsize, count;
char **searchword;
int *wordcount;
int *strlength;

typedef struct _params{
int num1;
int num2;
}params;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *childfunc(void *arg)
{

int size, i, j, k, t, start, end, len, flag = -1;

int result;

params *a = (params *)arg;
start = a->num1;
end = a->num2;


while(1){

if(start == 0 || start == fsize)
break;
if(buffer[start]!= ' '  && buffer[start] != '\n' && buffer[start] != '\t')
start++;
else
break;
}

while(1){

if(end == fsize)
break;
if(buffer[end] != ' ' && buffer[end] != '\n' && buffer[end] != '\t')
end++;
else
break;
}

for(i = 0; i < count; i++){

len = strlength[i];
for(j = start; j<(end - len + 1); j++){ 

if(buffer[j] == searchword[i][0]){ 

flag = 0; 
for(k = j +1; k<j + len; k++){
if(buffer[k] != searchword[i][k-j])
{
flag = 1; 
break;

}

}
if(flag == 0){

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
wordcount[i]++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);// mutex unlocking
sleep(1);
flag = -1;

}
}

}

}

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

FILE *fp;
char *inputFile;
pthread_t *tid;
int *status;
int inputNumber, i, j, diff, searchstart, searchend;
int result = 0;

count = argc -3;
inputNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
inputFile = argv[2];

searchword = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*count); 
tid = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*inputNumber);
strlength = (int *)malloc(4*count);
status = (int *)malloc(4*inputNumber);
wordcount = (int *)malloc(4*count);

for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
searchword[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[i+3]) + 1));
for(i = 3; i < argc; i++)
strcpy(searchword[i-3], argv[i]); 
fp = fopen(inputFile, "r"); 
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
fsize = ftell(fp); 
rewind(fp); 
buffer = (char *)malloc(1*fsize);

fread(buffer, fsize, 1, fp); 

diff = fsize / inputNumber; 
if(diff == 0)
diff = 1;

for(i = 0; i < count ; i++){
strlength[i] = strlen(searchword[i]);    
wordcount[i] = 0; 
}


for(i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++){

searchstart = 0 + i*diff;
searchend = searchstart + diff; 

if(searchstart > fsize)
searchstart = fsize; 

if(searchend > fsize) 
searchend = fsize;

if( i == inputNumber -1) 
searchend = fsize;
params a;
a.num1 = searchstart;
a.num2 = searchend;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

result = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, childfunc, (void *)&a);

if(result < 0){
perror("pthread_create()");
}

}

//스레드 받는 부분

for(i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++){
result = pthread_join(tid[i], (void **)status);

if(result < 0)
perror("pthread_join()");
}
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex); // mutex 해제
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
printf("%s : %d \n", searchword[i], wordcount[i]);

for(i = 0; i < count; i++) //동적메모리해제
free(searchword[i]);
free(searchword);

free(buffer);
free(tid);
free(strlength);
free(wordcount);
free(status);

fclose(fp);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params a; // new a for each loop, previous a no longer exists
a.num1 = searchstart;
a.num2 = searchend;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

result = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, childfunc, (void *)&a);

if(result < 0){
perror("pthread_create()");
}

} // a goes out of scope here
```

You pass each thread the address of `a`, but then `a` goes out of scope immediately after you create the thread. So the thread now has the address of some random leftover junk on the stack.

You need to have some conception of ownership of any object that's accessed by more than one thread like `a` is here. It can be owned by the thread that called `pthread_create`, owned by the newly-created thread, or jointly owned. But you have to be consistent. You have neither of these, why?

Is `a` owned only be the thread that called `pthread_create`? No, because the newly-created thread has a pointer to it and accesses it through that pointer. So the thread that called `pthread_create` cannot destroy it.

Is `a` owned only be the thread created by `pthread_create`? No, because it's on the stack of the thread that called `pthread_create` and will cease to exist when the next loop comes around.

Is `a` jointly owned? Well, no, because the thread that called `pthread_create` can destroy the object *before* the newly-created thread accesses it.

So no sane model of multi-thread use is followed by `a`. It's broken.

One common solution to this problem is to allocate a new structure (using `malloc` or `new`) for each thread, fill it in, and pass the thread the address of the structure. Let the thread `free` (or `delete`) the structure when it's done with it.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me an insight. Now I am going to try it!